# Cannot install RStudio on CentOS 6.4

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to install RStudio on Centos 6.4 with an already installed R version.

I got the following error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) is needed by rstudio-server-0.97.336-x86_64
libgfortran.so.1()(64bit) is needed by rstudio-server-0.97.336-x86_64
libssl.so.6()(64bit) is needed by rstudio-server-0.97.336-x86_64
```

Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed this error following this link:
http://jermdemo.blogspot.com.es/2011/08/installing-rstudio-server-on-scientific.html

You have to install some dependencies:

```
yum install libcrypto.so.6 -y
yum install libgfortran.so.1 -y
yum install libssl.so.6 -y
yum install openssl098e-0.9.8e -y
yum install gcc41-libgfortran-4.1.2 -y
yum install pango-1.28.1 -y
```

and the tricky one:

```
wget ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.0/x86_64/os/Packages/compat-
libgfortran-41-4.1.2-39.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh compat-libgfortran-41-4.1.2-39.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

and install Rstudio with no-deps flag:

```
rpm -Uvh --nodeps rstudio-server-0.97.336-x86_64.rpm
rstudio-server verify-installation
```

Comment: It would be worth posting this solution to the RStudio forum as well -- people often ask questions there about installing/building RStudio on non-mainstream OSes.